# Adding Carbon in Model for custom timestamp

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, php-carbon

I have created my own timestamp (beside updated_at & created_at) in database and filled it with seeder. Example data looks like this:

```
| id  |user|start_at (my timetable)| |   created_at        | updated_at
| 194 | 47 | 2015-01-21 00:00:00 | | 2016-09-25 16:48:48 | 2016-09-25 16:48:48 |
```

Also I added in my Model:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
}

public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
}

public function getStartAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
}
```

Now I try in my Controller:

```
$val->updated_at->diffForHumans();  // works
$val->created_at->format('d M Y'); // works

$val->start_at->format('d M Y'); // doesn't work
```

---

When I `var_dump`:

```
start_at:
 public 'date' => string '2016-10-12 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
 public 'timezone_type' => int 3
 public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)

created_at:
  +"date": "2016-09-25 16:48:48.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
```

---

**Update: Now I added `protected $dates = ['start_at']`**

```
dd($val->start_at); // gives '2014-08-03 00:00:00'
dd($val->start_at->format('d M Y') // fails
```

Error:

> Unexpected data found.
>   The separation symbol could not be found
>   Data missing

Comment: It should be working this way. Could you remove the get attribute functions from your modal? These are not nessecary in this case. Just using the $dates property suffices. Maybe the use of the getAttribute functions causes Laravel to double this transformation, which may return an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add start_at to $dates attribute of your model. You need to write custom setters or getter for this neither for created_at or updated_at attributes.

```
protected $dates = [
        'start_at',
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Mentioned start_at as carbon inastamce.

In your model add following code

```
protected $dates = [
        'start_at ',
    ];
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Now, I started getting: 'Unexpected data found.
The separation symbol could not be found
Data missing' dd($var->start_at);